# JS encodeURIComponenet not working

Tags: javascript, encodeuricomponent

I have an incoming message hitting my XSL page. On this XSL page I have javascript to catch it and place the items in the appropriate places.

There is the possibility that these messages can have double quotes and other escape characters.

I am using

```
parent.myForm.hiddenValue.value = encodeURIComponent(<xsl:value-of select="INCOMING/MESSAGE/BLAH">)
```

This works if the message has special characters but seems to give me a JS error if it does not. 
If the value coming in is nature. It will give me the error, nature is undefined.

Any ideas on how to use encode for both scenarios?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIGURED IT OUT Place single quotes around XSL

```
encodeURIComponent('<xsl:value-of select="BLAH/BLAH/BLAH"/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not quoting the string that you're passing to the function e.g.

encodeURIComponent("nature")

Comment: Sometimes the string will come quoted sometimes it will not. How am i supposed to account for both?

Comment: If i place quotes around the XSL, then it breaks.

Comment: fIGURED IT OUT Place single quotes around XSL 
encodeURIComponent('<xsl:value-of select="BLAH/BLAH/BLAH"/>')